# Efficiently moving and processing large files between sftp, server and network with Apache Camel

Tags: performance, apache-camel

I am copying large (600mb) files from sftp, doing additional processing on some of them, and storing them on a network location. My question is, how do i do this efficiently?

This would be the most straightforward way:

```
// just copy
from(sftp://user@domain.nl:22/folder)
  .to(file:////mnt/networkfolder/copy)

// do some processing
from(sftp://user@domain.nl:22/folder?include=important.*)
  .to(MyBean)
  .to(file:////mnt/networkfolder/processed)
```

However, this makes two trips to sftp.
I could do this:

```
// just copy
from(sftp://user@domain.nl:22/folder)
  .to(file:////mnt/networkfolder/copy)

// do some processing
from(file:////mnt/networkfolder/copy?include=important.*)
  .to(MyBean)
  .to(file:////mnt/networkfolder/processed)
```

But then i move the files from the network back to the server for processing (or at least i think that is what will happen.)

So my hunch is this would be the best way:

```
// get files to my server
from(sftp://user@domain.nl:22/folder)
  .to(file:////workdirectory)

// do the processing, then move to network
from(file:////workdirectory?include=important.*)
  .to(MyBean)
  .to(file:////mnt/networkfolder/processed)

// copy
from(file:////workdirectory?delete=true)
  .to(file:////mnt/networkfolder/copy)
```

Will the two routes starting in the workdirectory interfere with each other?
Is this the best way and does it matter in terms of network traffic and speed?

Comment: Use one consumer and pass that to a seda queue. The seda queue can have multiple consumers thus you will pick up a file send it to seda which will do processing in parrallel.